# Red blob on kesar mango tree (grown from seed in UK)

Tags: identification, diseases

Last June (10 months ago) I planted a Kesar Mango seed. After we cut of two leaves to stunt its growth, two branches grew (FYI).

Now, a very small red blob has appeared on top of it (see picture). A spiders web was on it, and brushed off (there for ~7 days). Is this blob a disease, or else what is it? Please could someone identify it.

Thanks.

Comment: The picture you refer to is not present...

Comment: @Bamboo oops... adding now

Comment: Nope, still not there...

Comment: This question cannot be properly answered without a photograph, and possibly more detail.